# Pointers and Linked List in C

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

I starting study pointers and linked list in C but i have a problem:

```
struct pointer
{
       int id;
       struct pointer *next;
};

int pop(struct pointer *head, struct pointer *tail);

main()
{
    struct pointer *head = NULL;
    head = (struct pointer*)malloc(sizeof(struct pointer));
    head->id=1;
    struct pointer *tail = head;
    tail->next=NULL;
    pop(head,tail);
    if (head==NULL) printf ("In main, head is NULL");
    else printf ("In main, head is NOT NULL");
}    

int pop(struct pointer *head, struct pointer *tail)
{
    int toReturn;
    struct pointer *toFree;
    if (head!=NULL)
    {
       toReturn = head->id;
       toFree = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(toFree);
       if (head==NULL)
          tail = head;
    }
    else toReturn = -1;
    if (head==NULL) printf ("In function, head is NULL\n");
    else printf ("In function, head is NOT NULL\n");
    return toReturn;
}
```

why is the output:

```
In function, head is NULL
In main, head is NOT NULL
```

I expect this:
    In function, head is NULL
    In main, head is NULL

This is my first experience with pointers in C and can't understand what i wrong

Comment: What exactly does the `pop` function do (or rather *should* do)?

Comment: `main(){` should be `int main ( void ) {`, and there should be a `return 0` statement at the end. In your `pop` function, the `else toReturn -= 1;` is wrong: `toReturn` is not initialized, you should set it to `0`. And don't cast the return value of `malloc`, pointers allocated on the heap should also be `free`'d when you're finished playing with that memory

Comment: I changed "main()" to "int main(void)" and added "return 0". In pop function is written "toReturn = -1" and not "toReturn -= 1". Without casting give me the error of "invalid conversion from void* to pointer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `pop` function you want to modify your `head` variable. Since C is passing parameters per value, you must give the address of `head` variable in order to modify its value. The same thing applies for `tail`.

Thus change your pop function from:

```
int pop(struct pointer *head, struct pointer *tail)
```

to:

```
int pop(struct pointer **head, struct pointer **tail)
```

And when calling this function, use `pop(&head, &tail);`

Comment: Doing this i get this error: toReturn = *head->id; (id has not been declared)

Comment: Error isn't there but I presume you didn't change `pop` method body. Since you are now using a pointer to `tail` and `head`, you should modify `head` to `*head` in the code, and `tail` to `*tail` to have the same behaviour than currently.

Comment: I modified as you can see in last comment "toReturn = *head->id"

Comment: @PascalNoPascensor should be `(*head)->id;`